# How to translate matlab function "roicolor" to scilab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, translate, scilab

How to translate matlab function "roicolor" to scilab

example code:

```
I = imread('rice.png');
BW = roicolor(I,128,255)
imshow(I)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do simply

```
BW = I>=128 & I<=255;
```

If you need a binary numerical result instead of a boolean one, just do afterwards:

```
BW = bool2s(BW);
```